# 2 different versions after upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04, xps

Upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 on dell xps 13 Core i5. `uname` shows `4.4.0-22-generic` and `lsb_release` shows 16.04 but when I go to the settings/details, I still see 14.04.

Can someone please assist with figuring it out?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about your repositories, listed in /etc/apt/sources.list ?

For example, in this line:

deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

After the repository address, it's written Xenial(16.04) or Trusty(14.04)?

Comment: my sources.list does not have that line

Comment: Can you put the content of your /etc/apt/sources.list please?